# Tool to create and copy special and non-printable character string to Clipboard for testing

Tags: testing, special-characters, non-printing-characters

I'm looking for a tool (ideally online) that lets me specify a string with special and unprintable character codes (e.g. < Code 32), by code, and copy it to the Clipboard for testing.

There are tools that do the opposite, like this one: https://www.soscisurvey.de/tools/view-chars.php - Here you can paste a string and see what special characters it contains.

I can write a Java program that specifies chars by code, but that's only useful to me as a developer when debugging (e.g. in Eclipse). The testing team needs a way to prepare strings with special chars based on codes, as below, copy them to the Clipboard as rendered strings, and then input them as test data into GUI fields.

```
String testStr = " ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" +
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" +
            "1234567890" +
            "`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+" +
            "[]
{}|" +
            ";':\"" +
            ",./<>?" +
            "\r\n" + // CARRIAGE RETURN, LINE FEED
            "\u00e1" + //     e1 //    0x00E1    225    LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH ACUTE
            "\u00e9" + //     e9 //   0x00E9    233    LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE
            "\u00ed" + //     ed //   0x00ED    237    LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE
            "\u00f3" + //     f3 //   0x00F3    243    LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH ACUTE
            "\u00fa" + //     fa //    0x00FA    250    LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH ACUTE
            "\u00fc" + //     fc //    0x00FC    252    LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS
            "\u00f1" + //     f1 //    0x00F1    241    LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH TILDE
            "\u00c1" + //     c1 //    0x00C1    193    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH ACUTE
            "\u00c9" + //     c9 //    0x00C9    201    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH ACUTE
            "\u00cd" + //     cd //    0x00CD    205    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH ACUTE
            "\u00d3" + //     d3 //    0x00D3    211    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O WITH ACUTE
            "\u00da" + //     da //    0x00DA    218    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH ACUTE
            "\u00dc" + //     dc //    0x00DC    220    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS
            "\u00d1" + //     d1 //    0x00D1    209    LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N WITH TILDE
            "\u00bf" + //     bf //    0x00BF    191    INVERTED QUESTION MARK
            "\u00a1"; //     a1 //   0x00A1    161    INVERTED EXCLAMATION MARK)
```

Also, I can't just copy rendered symbols from various online listings of character codes, since unprintable chars < Code 32 will be masked by the browser. I've looked into Notepad++ plugins, but they're also not that straightforward. In Notepad++, I can type Alt+[Code] to insert a special character, but anything <32 will be masked and I can't copy it for my purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I also found a Notepad++ solution. Click **Edit -> Character Panel**. From the character panel, double-click in the 3rd column the special char you want to insert.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`CyberChef` seems like a tool you could use. It has an online version [here](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/) or you can grab it via sources from [github](https://github.com/gchq/CyberChef). It's a swiss army knife for text processing (encoding, decoding, deciphering). For your use case select `From Charcode` from `operations` and use base 10.
[image]

I was able to copy the non-printables to Notepad ++ with it.

Comment: I can't select non-printable chars there (< Code 32).

Comment: I've edited my answer, you code sample made me suggest the windows char map - sorry.